# how to use maps and slider drawer in same xml for android activity

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout

So the situation is that I want to show a google map on main page along with a slider drawer that opens on slide from left to right.
I am able to achieve the same using below xml.

So, now the problem is that even when drawer is not opened, I am not able to communicate with maps i.e. on touch i am not able to move the map or use zoom functio. However, the drawer is working and also there is no runtime error.

xml I used is this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- <fragment
    android:id="@+id/badMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" /> -->

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

```
     Any ideas on how to make google maps touchable?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

....
```

Comment: thanks for help!! I used it and it is showing a ClassCastException that DrawerLayout cannot be cast to MapView.

Comment: Check your id in java in onCreate when you try to initialize DrawerLayout, I guess you have put your MapView id instead of that